# Bad -alloc() while adding elements in vector in a function

Tags: c++, vector, runtime-error, bad-alloc

I'm getting an error line 42 "p.pushback(c);"of bad alloc () while adding elements to vector p in the program .  What can be the possible reason for the error. [Live Example](https://ideone.com/bc7dsO)

```
void factorisation(lld N)
{

    lld i=0;
    sieve();
    while(prime[i]*prime[i]<=N)
    {
        lld c=0;
        while(N%prime[i]==0)
        {
            N/=prime[i];
            ++c;
            if(N%prime[i]!=0)
            {
                    cout<<prime[i]<<" "<<c<<endl;
                   factors.push_back(prime[i]);
                   p.push_back(c);

            }


        }

      ++i;
    }
    if(N!=1)
    {
        cout<<N<<" "<<1<<endl;
    factors.push_back(N);
    p.push_back(1);
    }

}
```

Comment: `std::bad_alloc` basically means you ran out of memory. How big is `p`?

Comment: initially they are empty and new primes prime[i] and their respective powers c are added to them.

Comment: I can see that. You didn't answer my question. What is the size of `p` when it crashes? Did you step in with a debugger?

Comment: when i tested it on my local machine second time

Comment: An n-element array is indexed from 0 to n-1.

Comment: Indeed, there's some out of bounds access. Also the line example doesn't exhibit the claimed behaviour, it's complaining about an invalid free.

Comment: @molbdnilo Thanks got your point !!